# How to move unlocated space out of the extended partition

Tags: partitioning, debian, gparted

I got his partition scheme:

[image: Screenshot from GParted]

I want to give the unlocated space to `/dev/sda1` (my system partition) from `/dev/sda2` my extended partition.

To reach that, I think i must move out the unlocated space out of `/dev/sda2`, right?

Unfortunately GParted does not offer the option to shrink `/dev/sda2` :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much you can do. Here's why:

[image: Partition layout with arrows pointing to OS partition and unallocated space]

This diagram shows physical layout of partitions on your disk. I have added arrows pointing to `/dev/sda1` and unallocated space. You can't merge them because they are not side by side - partitions have to be continuous.

You could merge them into one logical partition if you had LVM set up. I have never used it myself, but I guess enabling it would involve loosing data on `sda1` and possibly on other partitions too.

Comment: I can't even resize sd6?

Comment: You probably could, but it's your `/home`, not `/`.

Comment: i mean sda2 sorry

Comment: I'm not sure why GParted won't let you do that. But why would you resize it?

Comment: to put the unlocated space outside sda2 :)

Comment: But why would you do that? All you could do with that space is create new partition in it, but you can already do that.

Comment: So I must delete all extended partitions, resize the system one, and then backup my /home partition? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite agree with @gronostaj's answer. What you are asking is quite possible to do (although it involves risk of data corruption, so make backups before proceeding).

In my method, I will bring the unallocated space to the left-most (top-most) section of my Extended Partition. After that is done, I will resize my Extended partition to leave out the unallocated space contiguous to `sda1`.

My method goes something like this:

- First, boot from a separate GParted/PartedMagic CD/USB.
- Then, using `gparted`:

  - Resize `sda6` to include all of your Unallocated Space.
  - Resize `sda6` again to leave out your unallocated space to the left of `sda6`.
  - Then, resize `swap` to include unallocated space in that, and then resize it again to leave out the unallocated space to the left of `swap`.
  - You will now finally have your unallocated space to the top-most/left-most section of your extended partition.
  - Now, resize your extended partition to leave out the unallocated space.
  - The left out unallocated space will now be contiguous to `sda1`. Huzzah!!